# Fargate task stops about 10s after is starts with no log output

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

My Fargate task keeps stopping after it's started and doesn't output any logs (awslog driver is selected).
[image]

The container does start up and stay running when i execute docker locally.

Docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  asterisk:
    build: .
    container_name: asterisk
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 10000-10099:10000-10099/udp
      - 5060:5060/udp
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:10.7

RUN {stuff-that-works-is-here}


# Keep Asterisk running in the foreground
ENTRYPOINT ["asterisk", "-f"]

# SIP port 
EXPOSE 5060:5060/udp

# RTP ports
EXPOSE 10000-10099:10000-10099/udp
```

my task execution role has full cloudwatch access for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the ECS task instance, expand the container section, the error should be shown there. I have attached a screen shot of it. Here is a screenshot[Screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHD4r.png)

Comment: `Stopped reason: Essential container in task exited` & i also see `exit code 132` if I expand the dropdown under container.

Comment: It seems similar to this issue, a Reddit thread on that [https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/bltx02/container_exits_with_132_with_no_logs/](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/bltx02/container_exits_with_132_with_no_logs/)

Answer (score 0):

The AWS log driver alone is not enough.
Unfortunately, Fargate doesn't create the log group for you unless you tell it to

See `Creating a log group` at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and the cause was the Health Check.

ECS dont have Health Check for UDP, so when you open a UDP port if you use Docker for the deploy (docker compose), it create a Health Check pointing to a TCP port, and since there was no open TCP ports for that range, the container reset itself due to Health Check.

I had to add a custom Resource to docker-compose:

```
x-aws-cloudformation:
  Resources:
    AsteriskUDP5060TargetGroup:
      Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup"
      Properties:
        HealthCheckProtocol: TCP
        HealthCheckPort: 8088
```

Basically I have a Health Check for a UDP port pointing to a TCP port. Its a "hack" to bypass this problem when the deploy is made with Docker.